Dragging JFrame to the top of the screen to maximize it automatically and dragging downward to restore it to NORMAL size
I would like to ask for help regarding code below.
Objectives:
I should be able to enlarge the JFrame to full screen whenever I'm dragging it to the top of the screen. Similarly if the JFrame is in full screen mode, whenever I drag it down it should return to the normal mode depends on the minimum size parameters.
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class DraggableFrame extends JFrame {
    private int posX = 0, posY = 0;
    private boolean isDraggingDown = false;

    public DraggableFrame() {
        // Initialize the JFrame
        setUndecorated(true);
        setSize(800, 600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        // Add mouse listener for dragging
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                posX = e.getX();
                posY = e.getY();
                isDraggingDown = false;
            }
        });

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                int x = e.getXOnScreen() - posX;
                int y = e.getYOnScreen() - posY;

                // Handle dragging while in full screen
                if (getExtendedState() == JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH) {
                    if (y > 0 && !isDraggingDown) {
                        isDraggingDown = true;
                        setExtendedState(JFrame.NORMAL);
                        setSize(800, 600); // Restore to initial size
                        setLocation(x, y);
                    } else if (y <= 0 && !isDraggingDown) {
                        // If the frame is dragged to the top while maximized, do nothing
                        return;
                    }
                } else {
                    setLocation(x, y);

                    // Check if dragged to the top
                    if (getY() <= 0) {
                        // Enlarge window to fullscreen without covering taskbar
                        GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
                        GraphicsDevice device = env.getDefaultScreenDevice();

                        Rectangle screenBounds = device.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds();
                        Insets screenInsets = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(device.getDefaultConfiguration());

                        int taskbarHeight = screenInsets.bottom;

                        setBounds(screenBounds.x, screenBounds.y, screenBounds.width, screenBounds.height - taskbarHeight);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        // Restore to normal size if dragged down while in fullscreen
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                if (getY() == 0 && getExtendedState() == JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH) {
                    setExtendedState(JFrame.NORMAL);
                    setSize(800, 600); // Restore to initial size
                    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            DraggableFrame frame = new DraggableFrame();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}

I tried to apply some code that I found all over the internet but it seems none of them worked as I expected.
What I want is the following:
I should be able to enlarge the JFrame to full screen whenever I'm dragging it to the top of the screen. Similarly if the JFrame is in full screen mode, whenever I drag it down it should return to the normal mode depends on the minimum size parameters.

One word: don't. What you're intending to do is known as violating the Principle of Least Astonishment. It will simply either annoy people, and/or make them think you're producing buggy software

The problem is this condition:
            // Handle dragging while in full screen
            if (getExtendedState() == JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH) {

You never set the frames extended state to JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH, that condition is therefore never true and you never reach to code that would switch the frame back to normal.
Since setting the frame to JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH obscures the task bar (which it seems you want to avoid) you need another indication when the frame is maximized.
You could do this by adding a bolean field maximized to your DraggableFrame and adjust it when necessary:
public class DraggableFrame extends JFrame {
    private boolean maximized = false;

    // ...
        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                int x = e.getXOnScreen() - posX;
                int y = e.getYOnScreen() - posY;

                // Handle dragging while in full screen
                if (maximized) {
                    if (y > 0 && !isDraggingDown) {
                        isDraggingDown = true;
                        setExtendedState(JFrame.NORMAL);
                        setSize(800, 600); // Restore to initial size
                        setLocation(x, y);
                        maximized = false;
                    } else if (y <= 0 && !isDraggingDown) {
                        // If the frame is dragged to the top while maximized, do nothing
                        return;
                    }
                } else {
                    setLocation(x, y);

                    // Check if dragged to the top
                    if (getY() <= 0) {
                        // Enlarge window to fullscreen without covering taskbar
                        GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
                        GraphicsDevice device = env.getDefaultScreenDevice();

                        Rectangle screenBounds = device.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds();
                        Insets screenInsets = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(device.getDefaultConfiguration());

                        int taskbarHeight = screenInsets.bottom;

                        setBounds(screenBounds.x, screenBounds.y, screenBounds.width, screenBounds.height - taskbarHeight);
                        maximized = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        // Restore to normal size if dragged down while in fullscreen
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                if (getY() == 0 && maximized) {
                    setExtendedState(JFrame.NORMAL);
                    setSize(800, 600); // Restore to initial size
                    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    maximized = false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
    // ...
}

Even better would be to either not use undecorated frames (since these work together with the Window Manager of your OS) or (if you need undecorated frames because you want to make a full-screen game) make the window full screen from the beginning.

Apology for the late response, however I tried your solution but it didn't work as expected.
When I'm dragging the frame at the top of the screen it turns to full screen but as soon as I release the mouse, it revert back to normal size.

@TechNovice yes, that is a problem and the reason is this line in the public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {} method: if (getY() == 0 && maximized) will trigger if you drag the frame to the top (which makes getY() return 0) and the frame is automatically maximized (which makes maximized true). Probably the code works as intended if you remove that mouse listener.

Let me check that and get back to you.
